# Hot to fix "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
function copyFields<T>(target: T, source: Partial<T>): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];  // Error
    }
    return target;
}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

copyFields(x, { b: 10, d: 20 });
```

Code above occurs the error `Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'`.

Doesn't `source` always a part of `target`?

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] | undefined` can be `undefined`, which cannot be assigned to type `Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]`.

Your input `source` may have a property that has been explicitly set to `undefined`, which would not be able to be assigned to the equivalent property on `target`.

You should check for this case, though it looks like this condition isn't enough for TypeScript to determine that it's definitely not `undefined`. However, you can then apply TypeScript's [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to make sure TypeScript realises this means the property is not `undefined`:

```
function copyFields<T>(target: T, source: Partial<T>): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        const sourceProp = source[id];
        if (typeof sourceProp !== 'undefined') {
          target[id] = sourceProp!;  // No error here
      }
    }
    return target;
}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

copyFields(x, { b: 10, d: 20 });
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOAHAngMRgUwDYAmAzgDwAqAfABRQCGATgOY5QBciZANIkXCPRBzsACg1i085CgEp2ZRAG8AUIlWJgceoip4WiGAX1Je-QdMUq1VlGCJQefATmH00iALwPTOANoGAugDcllaqMMDaUOioOHARJk4ubgCE7p4A5OAEOMAwYDgE6ebKoaF0TCx+BP4eXomuqMmBqgD0LYgAcnCIOPSuWgAWvTghagC+oxNW9Cz8SOXMUMETSrr2AB61Coi07ACM3ABG7ABM3BDsAMzcBOwALIhjwUooGNj4xFTr3NvHiHsABhupwBj2kgSAA)

Comment: Partial typing makes it possibly undefined

Comment: Yeah, I'd have hoped the condition would have been enough to tell TypeScript to refine it from `T[Extract<keyof T, string>] | undefined` to `Exclude<T[Extract<keyof T, string>] | undefined, undefined>`, but apparently that's not how it works.